# Listing PDF files from a folder in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Im new to ASP.NET development.I have an Intranet site where i have this task of showing PDF files from server. At present i have just used an IFRAME and three link buttons. I want to make it a dynamic one. that means if the file is 4 four link buttons should be created.

So I thought a "Tree View" will do better for this requirment. but it should look rich in page not like an ordinary tree view.

How to have a tree View that should dynamically add child nodes depending on the number of files in the folder and when the user clicks the node the corresponding file should be loaded into iframe?

Comment: better store the url of file in db..then code as to retrieve the url and pass it to linkbuttons...this is very simple to do if db is used..

Comment: But I can get the URLs directly from my local server.I have all those URLs.but no idea how to bring the tree view..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display link buttons, then you can use a repeater control and add link buttons for each pdf file(row present in table) and set the navigate url to the pdf's link.

Comment: But I have two categories "Global" and "Specific" under which these PDF files to be shown. So Tree view would be best for this task.. Can you pls provide sample codes for the same task using tree view??